# Aggregating and mapping observations from an open questionnaire

Tags: r, dataframe

**Summary**

I want to create a boxplot like this one displaying the most frequent perceived problems in every neighborhood of a city. [image: Sample boxplot with real data]

Unfortunately, the boxplot is useless as it is, since the data I am using comes from an open questionnaire and it has two main problems:

1. There are a lot of irrelevant answers (by irrelevant I refer to those which are used by only one or few people)
2. There are problems that refer to the same concept but have been rephrased differently and thus are counted as something different.

In order to make it more useful I would like to aggregate irrelevant answers in a single group "eg: `other problems` and rename the problems that mean the same so they are worded exactly and thus can be displayed properly in the barplot. Unfortunately I didn't succeed in doing so.

**Detailed explanation**

Let's take a look at a sample code (The names on the dataframe are just examples: I have modified them for the sake of clarity so it makes it easier to understand that two or more problems are related, but the real terms can't always be deduced from a regular expression):

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df= read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/bUxANQw6")

problems = df %>%
  select(Problems) %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(Total = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(Total))
```

Which result in the following dataframe:

```
> problems
Source: local data frame [27 x 2]

          value Total
1     Problem 1   282
2     Problem 3   268
3     Problem 2   186
4   No problems   160
5     Problem 4    76
6     Problem 5    68
7     Problem 6     6
8     Problem 7     5
9  Doesn't know     4
10    Problem 8     2
..          ...   ...
>
```

As can be seen we have 27 problems, and looking at them more carefuly we could stablish some groups:

1. Relevant data: Problems 1 to 7 + `No Problems` and `Doesn't know`
2. Synomyms: we have `Problem 9`, `Problem 9'`, `Problem 9''` or `Problem 9'''` (amongst others)
3. Irrelevant data, which should be grouped under a single label, like "Other Problems": Problems 12 to 18

**My suggested approach**

That's what I thought I could do in order to overcome these two problems:

In order to deal with **synonyms**, I thought of renaming the synonym values into a single one, possibly using `revalue` command, something like this:

```
df$Problems = revalue(df$Problems, c('Problem 9’' = 'Problem 9',
                                     'Problem 9’’' = 'Problem 9',
                                     'Problem 9’’’' = 'Problem 9'))
```

However, as a R newbie (and newbie to programming languages, as well) I think there should be a faster way to achieve that, since the task of maintaining a "synonyms' dictionary" will be very tedious and will be growing when getting more replies.

In order to deal with **irrelevant answers**, I could take a similar approach, and revalue them as `Other problems`, but I would like to do it in an automated way, since the list of irrelevant terms will be growing as the questionnaire has not yet finished and I cannot map all of them manually (eg: map all values which have been voted by less than 5 people `Total < 5`). I guess I should create a function and use a control structure (`for ... in`) but I have not yet succeeded on that.

Since I need to display a boxplot of the answers grouped by neighborhoods, I'm afraid I can't use the `problems` dataframe as it is. So although it is useful to calculate total number of votes per problem, I do not know what to do with it other than use it as informative data. On the other hand, I cannot determine if an answer is irrelevant based only on the replies received in each neighborhood, as it would bias the results, since it is expected that different neighborhoods may have different problems.

Any help with these two problems will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: #2 Irrelevant answers: you can aggregate them by e.g. doing `%>% mutate(value=ifelse(Total<2, "Other Problems", value))`. #1 Synonyms: You are looking for ways to deduplicate your data. Have a look at the examples for the `RecordLinkage` package and its functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, lukeA. I'll take a look at RecordLinkage tutorials, as it seems complex to handle, but very suitable.  I really loved the mutate code you showed, very useful. Unfortunately I can't use it as that would remove any problem that has received less than 2 votes per neighborhood, whereas I should remove any problem that has received less than two votes overall. (I have updated explanation). Could you help me with that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look of your data and code. Your data frame, `problems` got `Problem 9’`, `Problem 7'` and so forth. So what you want is to remove `’` and `'`. That is your task one. You can achieve this task with the following line.

```
problems$value <- gsub(pattern = "’+|'+", replacement = "", x = problems$value)
```

You can achieve the other task by using `which()`. You want to find rows which are `Total < 5`. Using `which()`, you can find indices. Then, you replace whatever in `value` in the rows with `Other problems`. I hope this is what you are after.

```
problems$value[which(problems$Total < 5)] <- "Other problems"
```

**DATA**

```
problems <- structure(list(value = c("Problem 1", "Problem 3", "Problem 2", 
"No problems", "Problem 4", "Problem 5", "Problem 6", "Problem 7", 
"Doesn't know", "Problem 8", "Problem 9", "Problem 9’", "Other problems", 
"Problem 10", "Problem 10’", "Problem 11", "Problem 11'", "Problem 12", 
"Problem 13", "Problem 14", "Problem 15", "Problem 16", "Problem 17", 
"Problem 18", "Problem 7'", "Problem 9’’", "Problem 9’’’"
), Total = c(282L, 268L, 186L, 160L, 76L, 68L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), .Names = c("value", "Total"))
```

EDIT

Seeing the OP's first comment, the following lines would make a data frame to draw a graphic.

```
count(df, Neighborhoods, Problems) -> temp

temp$Problems <- gsub(pattern = "’+|'+", replacement = "", x = temp$Problems)

temp$Problems[which(temp$n < 5)] <- "Other problems"

group_by(temp, Neighborhoods, Problems) %>%
summarize(Total = sum(n)) -> temp2
```

Comment: Thank you, jazzurro.  Unfortunately I can't make it like that, as the name of the problems are completely different (I just used `problem 9` and `problem 9'` as the original answers are in Spanish and may not have any sense for most readers here. I am not sure I can use problems dataframe, as I need to make further operations with `df`like creating a boxplot displaying answers grouped by neighborhood.  I'm afraid I cannot use regular expressions to fix that, although I will take note of your answer for the future, as it is something I wanted to learn.

I have updated my question with this info

Comment: @CarlosCámara Thanks for your message. I added another solution. Let me know if the new solution gives you your expected outcome. If it does, all you need is to work on graphic codes for ggplot2 or others.

Comment: Thanks again, jazzurro. Very interesting your solution. Unfortunately I can't use it as it is, as that does not allow me to stratify problems per neighborhood and if I apply it to `df` it would remove any problem that has received less than 5 votes per neighborhood, whereas I should remove any problem that has received less than two votes overall. (I have updated explanation). Could you help me with that as well?

Comment: @CarlosCámara Could you be able to upload a minimal reproducible data? I am happy to help you but it is hard for me to see exactly what you are looking for without your real data. If you can leave an expected output, that would help So users to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure! I have updated the description with the expected outcome. The data I used to do the barplot is exactly the same I provided in the dataframe, but I just replaced real problems' names with `problem 1`, `problem 2`... `problem 7'` and so on so it is easier for non Spanish speakers to understand what the data is and that there are different ways to name the same problem. However, if you need more clarifications I will be more than happy to provide them. Thank you very much for your time, disposition and patience.

Comment: @CarlosCámara One clear change necessary is the following. `temp$Problems[which(temp$n < 2)] <- "Other problems"`. Could you run my codes under EDIT with the line I provided in this comment and see what happens? You will see the numbers of different problems for each neighborhood.

Comment: Yes... I can see the problems per neighborhood, which is great. Unfortunately I have discarded all problems that were voted less than 2 times in a single neighborhood, which may biass the results. I could prevent that by changing first line of your code like this `count(df, Problems) -> temp` so I could aggregate all problems voted less than 2 times overall. But then I wouldn't know how to relate each problem to each neighborhoods, like you do in `temp$Problems[which(temp$n < 2)] <- "Other problems"`

Comment: After reproducing everything from scratch, your code worked fine, except for the part of synonyms' dictionary, as I cannot deduce them from a regular expression formula. Accepting this answer as solution, though. Thank you very much for your detailed explanations.

Comment: @CarlosCámara Pleasure to help you. :)